# Mathematica's spacing of symbol accents when typesetting mathematical formulas

Tags: printing, wolfram-mathematica, frontend, typesetting

Mathematica appears to have difficulty horizontally aligning accents (*e.g.* bars, hats, and tildes) when placed on top of certain mathematical symbols.

Here's a simple example:

[image]

Using the AdjustmentBox typesetting construct (or Alt-Left/Right arrow in the frontend), one can manually adjust the relative horizontal position of the hat and the symbol *j* to produce the more aesthetically pleasing:

[image]

There are two problems here:

1).  It is inconvenient and time-consuming to make these manual adjustments when this should really be the job of the  typesetting engine proper.  Indeed, LaTeX is able to position accents correctly over all of the standard symbols (roman and greek letter forms) without the need to manually tweak their relative positioning.

2).  The relative re-positioning of the symbols using AdjustmentBox is lost when exporting the Notebook to PDF for printing and re-distribution.

**Question:**

Does anyone have any suggestions for a more convenient way (preferably automatic) to improve the typeset quality of formulas in Mathematica notebooks that use accents, that preferably will also survive export of the notebook document to PDF format before printing?

Comment: Both issues you point out seem like legitimate bugs to me. Please be sure to report them to Wolfram Research support.

Comment: @ragfield:  Wonder if WRI staff regularly review Mathematica-related posts on StackExchange.  If not, they should be :)

Comment: Regardless, my experience with software companies has repeatedly shown me that A) you can never assume a software developer already knows about a bug (regardless of how obvious you think it is) and B) software developers tend to place a higher priority on bugs which are reported more frequently.  So if you want these issues to be addressed in a future update it's always in your best interest to report them.

Comment: The address of WRI support is support@wolfram.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select " ĵ " from the Windows character map and paste it in.

```
Style[ĵ, Italic, 24, Bold, FontFamily -> "Times"]
```

[image]

Also you can assign it to an input alias (borrowing from Andrew Moylan)

```
n = SelectedNotebook[];
SetOptions[n, 
 InputAliases -> 
  Append[Options[n, InputAliases][[1, 2]], "j^" -> "ĵ"]]
```

Typing `Esc`j^`Esc` produces ĵ.

Comment: Looks like LaTeX's horizontal alignment of math accents over dotted letter forms (*i* and *j*) performs better on the undotted versions too -- good suggestion.  On the other hand, Mathematica's positioning of the accents on other letters is also problematic, so this is still an issue worth raising with their support team given that Wolfram is trying increase adoption of its notebook format (via CDF) in the technical publishing field.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I do not think that this is possible.
You may ask Wolfram Research to include unicode character 0135 , i.e., they should add \[JHat], like 
\[IHat]. Then italics display nicely.